# How to loop datareader when passing to wcftestclient?

Tags: c#, sql, wcf, loops, datareader

When i trying to view more than one row in database from wcf, i just got one last row

i create this service

```
public dcTransaction SelectMasterTransaction(DateTime date1, DateTime date2)
    {
        dcTransaction dcTrans = new dcTransaction();
        string conString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DBCS"].ConnectionString;
        using (con = new SqlConnection(conString))
        {
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("spViewMasterTransaction", con);
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

            SqlParameter parameterDate1 = new SqlParameter();
            parameterDate1.ParameterName = "@date1";
            parameterDate1.Value = date1;
            cmd.Parameters.Add(parameterDate1);

            SqlParameter parameterDate2 = new SqlParameter();
            parameterDate2.ParameterName = "@date2";
            parameterDate2.Value = date2;
            cmd.Parameters.Add(parameterDate2);


            con.Open();

            SqlDataReader dtReader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
            while (dtReader.Read())
            {
                dcTrans.no_trans = int.Parse(dtReader["no_trans"].ToString());
                dcTrans.name = dtReader["name"].ToString();
                dcTrans.sum = int.Parse(dtReader["sum"].ToString());
                dcTrans.dates = DateTime.Parse(dtReader["dates"].ToString());
            }
        }
        return dcTrans;
    }
```

What i got here is, the wcftestclient show only the last record that i request too..
ex : from date 1/1/2010 to 1/1/2014 (the sql query is written in stored procedure in my sql server)

and then when i give wcftestclient a value 1/1/2010 to 1/1/2014, the wcftestclient just return last date record, i think it won't print the loop, what am i missing here? i think WHILE(dataReader.read()) is already loop right?

Here is my stored procedure in my sql server

```
 CREATE PROCEDURE spViewMasterTransaksi
@date1 datetime,
@date2 datetime

AS
BEGIN
select * from MasterTransaction WHERE date >= @date1 AND date <= @date2

END
```

when i execute my stored procedure via sql server it seems fine, it show the date that between the value i enter..

Comment: And just a side note, SQL will be returning those fields as `int`s already. You don't need to parse the string representations. It isn't what's causing your problems, but that's a pretty inefficient way of doing it. You should also add some `using` statements. I'll make both of these changes in my code to show an example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You aren't returning a list of objects. You do the loop, but each item overwrites the previous one's values.

You could look into `yield return` here and return an `IEnumerable<dcTransaction>`, or just do a classic `List<T>` and add on each pass through the loop.

```
public IEnumerable<dcTransaction> SelectMasterTransaction(DateTime date1, DateTime date2)
{
    string conString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DBCS"].ConnectionString;
    using (con = new SqlConnection(conString))
    using(SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("spViewMasterTransaction", con))
    {
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

        SqlParameter parameterDate1 = new SqlParameter();
        parameterDate1.ParameterName = "@date1";
        parameterDate1.Value = date1;
        cmd.Parameters.Add(parameterDate1);

        SqlParameter parameterDate2 = new SqlParameter();
        parameterDate2.ParameterName = "@date2";
        parameterDate2.Value = date2;
        cmd.Parameters.Add(parameterDate2);

        con.Open();

        using (SqlDataReader dtReader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
        {
            while (dtReader.Read())
            {
                dcTransaction dcTrans = new dcTransaction();

                dcTrans.no_trans = dtReader.GetInt32(0); // Index for "no_trans"
                dcTrans.name = dtReader.GetString(1); // Index for "name"
                dcTrans.sum = dtReader.GetInt32(2); // Index for "sum"
                dcTrans.dates = dtReader.GetDateTime(3); // Index for "dates"

                yield return dcTrans;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: this is what i do, i change the function to "public List<dcTransaksi> SelectMasterTransaksi(DateTime tanggalAwal, DateTime tanggalAkhir)" but the return dcTrans, give me an error, like "cannot implicitly convert type dcTransaction to System.Collection.generic.list<dctransaction>

Comment: @KeVin I altered my answer to show an example of `yield return`. But yes, that works as well. It depends how you want it to play out.

Comment: still return just one record, but it showed up, length=1, but my database record have more than that..

Comment: Are you sure you aren't limiting the result count with your `WHERE` clause?

Comment: Also, @KeVin, what happens when you step through this? Does it seem to step through the `while` multiple times?

Comment: nope, but when i execute my stored procedure, it the result is fine, i update my stored procedure in my question

Comment: It shouldn't make any difference, but try skipping around the sproc. Just set the command text directly and see if that behaves differently at all.

Comment: see sajeetharan answer, that what i missed

Comment: The only difference I see between my answer and his is that he's using a list, which isn't as good a way to do it as the `yield return` pattern...

Comment: sorry i didn't notice, that u do "new" in while loop, that's why my code doesn't work before, i change your answer as my solution :D

Comment: why it's IEnumerable<object> is better than List<object>?

Comment: It's a little complicated, but the gist is that `IEnumerable<T>` executes using *deferred execution*, which means that it doesn't actually execute until you use the result. That doesn't make much of a difference in many cases, but there are a few times when it does. For instance, if you're looping through the list with a `foreach` and you `break` out, you won't have had to load the full thing into memory first. It also has a quicker turn-around time in that you can begin printing to the UI as soon as the query returns, rather than having to iterate through everything twice.

Comment: I guess that's really the key advantage. Instead of looping through the rows then looping through the result of that, you only have to loop once. It's really a theoretical advantage more than a practical one in many applications, but it's still good practice to get into. It also reduces memory consumption, because the GC can pick up objects much sooner than it could if they were still stored in a `List<T>`.

Answer (score 2):

You are returning a single object, Change your Method Definition to return `List<dcTransaction>` like below

```
 public List<dcTransaction>  SelectMasterTransaction(DateTime date1, DateTime date2)
        {
            List<dcTransaction> result = new List<dcTransaction>();
            string conString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DBCS"].ConnectionString;
            using (con = new SqlConnection(conString))
            {
                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("spViewMasterTransaction", con);
                cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                SqlParameter parameterDate1 = new SqlParameter();
                parameterDate1.ParameterName = "@date1";
                parameterDate1.Value = date1;
                cmd.Parameters.Add(parameterDate1);
                SqlParameter parameterDate2 = new SqlParameter();
                parameterDate2.ParameterName = "@date2";
                parameterDate2.Value = date2;
                cmd.Parameters.Add(parameterDate2);
                con.Open();
                SqlDataReader dtReader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
                while (dtReader.Read())
                {
                    dcTransaction dcTrans = new dcTransaction();
                    dcTrans.no_trans = int.Parse(dtReader["no_trans"].ToString());
                    dcTrans.name = dtReader["name"].ToString();
                    dcTrans.sum = int.Parse(dtReader["sum"].ToString());
                    dcTrans.dates = DateTime.Parse(dtReader["dates"].ToString());
                    result.Add(dcTrans); 
                }
            }
            return result;
        }
```

Comment: awesome! are we always have to initiate List<object>?